# How to make each row of columns in data.table unique, alphabetized, and shifted left

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I have a `data.table` `DT_in` with an ID number column first and then only a 3 capital letter entry (Like "AAA" or"ZZZ") or a "" (Not NA) in each entry in all the other columns.

I want to take a row from the `data.table`:

1. make it unique (no repeating 3 letter entries across the row)
2. put it in alphabetical order,
3. and then shift the "" entries to the left taking up the first 'n' columns left of the ID number with all blank entries to the right. (The proposed duplicate answer only addresses this issue and not the others)

I want this to happen for each row in the table.

I tried nested for loops but could not get it to work how I wanted.

```
library(data.table)

# Given this input
DT_in <- data.table(
V1 = c("135", "428", "837", "580"),
V2 = c("AAA", "FFF", "", ""),
V3 = c("BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "ZZZ"),
V4 = c("", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA"),
V5 = c("BBB", "", "CCC", "AAA")
)



# I would like this output organizing each row individually (not columns) 
DT_out <- data.table(
V1 = c("135", "428", "837", "580"),
V2 = c("AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA"),
V3 = c("BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "ZZZ"),
V4 = c("", "FFF", "", ""),
V5 = c("", "", "", "")
)
```